# expect script said command not found

Tags: expect

I am new to expect script, and I am trying to let it automatically enroll into our SCCM.  I wonder what is wrong with my expect script?

thanks so much!!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect


## Set all variables
set server "aaa.com"
set username "ad\username"
set pass "password"

## Enroll into SCCM
spawn ./tools/CMEnroll -s $server -ignorecertchainvalidation -u $username
expect "Please enter your password."
send $pass
send \n 
expect "Successfully enrolled"
interact

exit 0
```

when I open terminal, and use ./expect.sh this file, it said :

```
sudo: ./expect.sh: command not found
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the execution permissions to your script? For example you can run:

```
$ chmod +x expect.sh
```

The explanation of `chmod +x` can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29589/chmod-ux-versus-chmod-x